# Can't find MX Master 3 in bluetooth menu

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my Logitech MX Master 3 to my machine. I am dual-booting Linux Mint and Windows on a Dell XPS 9310. The mouse connects fine to Windows. However, when I reboot into Linux Mint it doesn't appear in the Bluetooth scan menu. I have tried using Blueman, restarting `bluetooth.service`, and removing `/var/lib/bluetooth`. I have tried to use `bluetoothctl` and `hcitool` to connect to it via the terminal but that is also unsuccessful. Any ideas on what is going on? How can I fix this?

Comment: On my Mint computers, my mouse only shows up when the setting is set to 2 on the mouse. However, the mouse still doesn't work. It pairs, connects, and indicates no problems, but there is no input from the mouse. Have you tried this? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth#Device_does_not_show_up_in_scan

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but I found a way that worked for me in Linux Mint.

Start a terminal and run `bluetoothctl`, then:

1. type `scan on` and locate the mac-address of your mouse.
2. `pair <mac-address>`
3. `connect <mac-address>`
4. `trust <mac-address>`

And my MX Master 3 started working, hope it helps.